# Word for someone who is "quietly reliable"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word that describes a "quietly reliable" person. i.e. someone who is conscientious as a matter of course, not expecting any praise or even mention of it, they are just habitually dependable, like a parent or friend who's always there for you.

I'm sure there are some words for it but I can't put my finger on them.

Comment: Are you looking for a noun or an adjective?

Comment: @Josh61 An adjective, though a noun might work as well.

Comment: What's wrong with *dependable*? It means trustworthy and reliable. The idea of "quiet" is something that would have to be added to any such description, I think.

Comment: @Robusto *Dependable* is pretty close. Perhaps I should be looking for a phrase or idiom, not just a single word.

Comment: Someone who's "got your back"?

Comment: "Solid" is another term, though the context needs to be established lest it be misinterpreted as referring to physical traits.

Comment: I have heard of incredibly reliable, quietly? reliable, probably who owns up the obligations quietly.

Comment: Re: *Perhaps I should be looking for a phrase or idiom, not just a single word.* Then why not just stick with "quietly reliable"? It's very descriptive and already concisely captures what you're after (you can save at most one word even if your quest for a single word is successful). While I doubt anyone would consider it "idiomatic", I actually quite like it (in part *because* it's a little on the colorful and uncommon side).

Comment: I quite like the phrase "quietly reliable".  It's meaning to me is slightly different than all the offered suggestions, and also feels very different tone-wise.  I'd keep it unless you had a good reason to change it.

Comment: In my workplace the synonym seems to be _'unnoticed'_...

Comment: You can also refer to someone as a "safe pair of hands". This works especially in a business setting for someone who quietly gets on with the day to day running of things. It's 3 words rather than one.

Comment: Note that if you're looking for a word that *just* means a person who doesn't seek out praise, you'd be looking for the word "humble", so "A humble worker" would be someone who does their job without seeking praise for it.

Comment: If you gave me two more words to use (phrase), you'd be my *go-to guy*.

Comment: I think I'll nominate "upstanding".  Doesn't necessarily imply "quiet", but does mean that the person is reliable and trustworthy.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

"steadfast".

This implies both reliability and a lack of drama. You could also go with "staunch", but that seems a little more likely to be *not quiet*.

Comment: "Staunch" was the first word that came to mind when I read this: "loyal and committed in attitude".  Not sure I agree with the "not quiet" bit, but I do agree that steadfast is a fine word for what the OP's looking for.

Answer (score 31):

How about *stalwart*? As an adjective, it means "loyal, reliable, and hard-working." but you could also use it as a noun if you were specifying who the person was loyal to?

Answer (score 20):

**Stolid** comes fairly close (via oxforddictionaries.com):

> calm, dependable, and showing little emotion or animation

Comment: Could you maybe include a source?

Comment: I've never heard this before, but it appears to be a genuine word. It's also kinda intuitive - it sounds like what someone would say if they couldn't decide between "solid" and "stoic", which pretty much fits the brief... +1!

Comment: Stolid is often used in a perjorative sense, meaning **dull** or **unimaginative**.

Answer (score 14):

an *unfailing* friend: not failing; not giving way; not falling short of expectation; completely dependable.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unfailing

Answer (score 12):

This is an easy one to overlook:

[Responsible](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/responsible) (From the Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary):

- having the **job or duty** of **dealing with or taking care** of something or someone
- able to be **trusted to do what is right** or to do the things that are **expected or required**
- involving important duties, decisions, etc., that you are **trusted to do**

This carries the full meaning of what you are trying to say.  This is a person that is not performing their duty for praise, or being especially noteworthy in their conduct, but just 'doing their job' and being dependable for things that are expected of them.  It's not glamarous by any means - it's just being mature and dependable.

Comment: I'm not convinced this explicitly implies "quietly" in the sense mentioned in the question.

Comment: @JonStory I believe it does.  " someone who is conscientious as a matter of course, not expecting any praise or even mention of it, they are just habitually dependable, like a parent or friend who's always there for you."  I couldn't think of a better way to describe a responsible person.

Comment: Indeed, I think this is the *most* "quiet" of the choices presented so far (17 answers as I write this).

Answer (score 8):

If you want a colloquial term, you could use "rock", as in "She's my rock."

Comment: Hello Bette, welcome to ELU. Good answer (I'm trying to filter out the connotations from rock music!)

Comment: Alternatively, works if you're looking for a Biblical term, since the Gospels have Jesus say something quite similar to that about Peter (whose name comes from the Greek for *rock*, so it was also a pun)

Comment: @KRyan A small correction. It's not so much a pun as much as Jesus making a declaration about the kind of person Peter is. If I recall correctly (and I'm pretty confident that I do), it is actually the occasion where Jesus gives him a new name of Peter (his previous name being Simon, hence Simon Peter).

Comment: Personally (Canadian/American English native), this phrase sounds incredibly odd. If someone told me someone was their "rock", I'd have to ask for clarification (unless it was something like, "they're solid as a rock").

Answer (score 7):

You want something short? The shortest I can think of is *trusty*:

> trusty *adj.* Dependable; faithful; reliable.

[From my physical *American Heritage Dictionary*, 2nd College Ed.]

Comment: Not from your **trusty** _American Heritage Dictionary_?

Comment: @dannysauer: Indeed, that dictionary is trusty!

Answer (score 7):

A surprisingly popular thread, and an interesting array of suggestions. Despite all of the *16* answers already provided, I believe I have a different angle.

> **Selfless**: having or showing great concern for other people and little or no concern for yourself

--[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/selfless)

Most of the other suggested words convey the sense of reliability, but do not necessarily reflect the "quiet" part of your request. A truly selfless person does not seek glory for themselves.

Answer (score 6):

Dependable is the first word that comes to my mind...

Comment: But it came to Robusto's even earlier.

Comment: A good suggestion that deserved its own post, and not limited to a comment.

Comment: this word is already in the OP.

Answer (score 5):

A "diligent" person tends to be reliable by nature, without fanfare.

Answer (score 5):

**Solid** - Its not the real definition of the word, but I think most people would understand whats meant.

Answer (score 3):

If you want something with a bit of an archaic tone, you could try *[yeomanly](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/yeomanly)*

> having the virtues attributed to yeomen, such as staunchness, loyalty, and courage

*Collins*

Comment: Is it formal.... ?

Comment: As a native US English speaker I wouldn't understand this in typical conversation. And I'm fairly certain most people would be even more confused by it ("what's a yeoman?")

Comment: @Daenyth The term *yeomanlike* is also used., similar to *workmanlike*. I did say it was archaic.

Comment: @bib You did, but some archaic terms are comprehensible to lay speakers, and some are not. I was just clarifying that (IME) this one is not, in case the OP didn't have the context to know.

Comment: @Daenyth I thought we were all about *expanding* people's knowledge and experiences. And I'm not urging it for everyday speech.

Answer (score 3):

> Probably, **time-tested** (TFD)
>
> (adj) : tested and proved to be reliable.

- ↔dependable, reliable - worthy of reliance or trust; "a reliable
  source of information"; "a dependable worker".

Comment: I've never heard "time-tested" for a person. Only for methods, items, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I’d like to add “unsung hero” to the list.

> ### Unsung Hero

From [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Unsung+hero):

> Someone who does a great job yet receives little or no recognition for that. An unsung hero usually refrains from claiming too much in return for his/her efforts.

From [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unsung+hero):

> A person who makes a substantive yet unrecognized contribution

Answer (score 2):

I'd consider [workhorse](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/workhorse):

> - a person who performs most of the work of a group task; a hardworking person
> - something that is markedly useful, durable, or dependable

Comment: +1. My manager at my first job called me a workhorse. Probably the most positive thing a boss has ever said to me.

Answer (score 1):

I like the expression  [be (always) there for sb](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/be-there-for-sb):

> - to be available to provide help and support for someone:
>     We haven't always been close, but she was there for me when I needed her.
>     Best friends are always there for each other in times of trouble.

[trustworthy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trustworthy) may also fit: (M-W)

> - able to be relied on to do or provide what is needed or right : deserving trust.

Answer (score 0):

*Sentinel* carries the proper denotation and connotation, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Steadfast has the right nuance of meaning. 
adjective
resolutely or dutifully firm and unwavering.
"steadfast loyalty"
synonyms:   loyal, faithful, committed, devoted, dedicated, dependable, reliable, steady, true, constant, staunch, solid, trusty 
Although I am stretching the meaning it is from the  Old English stedefæst. It is comprised of two parts: stede (“stead, place”) + -fæst (“fixed”)
Silent is simply inferred from context

Answer (score -1):

A noun might be *trump*, as defined by [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trump):

> *Informal* A reliable or admirable person.

[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trump), too, emphasizes the quality and virtue of a *trump* with:

> a dependable and exemplary person

It is not used [in this way](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+is+a+trump%2C+she+is+a+trump%2C+you+are+a+trump&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20is%20a%20trump%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshe%20is%20a%20trump%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20are%20a%20trump%3B%2Cc0) often, so [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/trump#trump) prefaces its definition with *dated*.

O. Henry uses it in his short story [*A Service of Love (1906)*](http://www.literaturecollection.com/a/o_henry/29/), in which hard times fall upon two married artists. 
The wife tells her husband that she has temporarily given up her schooling and taken up tutoring so they can still eat while he continues his studies. 
The husband, realizing her sacrifice, commends her with:

> "All right," said Joe, reaching for the blue scalloped vegetable
>   dish. "But I hate for you to be giving lessons. It isn't Art. But
>   you're a trump and a dear to do it."

She does it without the expectation of praise, since (in a spoiler tag because it's O. Henry):

> She was unable to find pupils and has been working instead in a laundry. (The husband finds out because he's been working in the engine-room of the same laundry.)